# Somar o resultado de uma variável em outra variável

Tags: java, sql, jasper-reports, ireport, jasper

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Desenvolvi um relatório no `iReport 5.5.1` onde somei os dados de uma coluna em uma variável pois precisa mostrar este total, e depois eu preciso pegar esses totais e somar tudo em uma nova Variável afim de mostrar o total macro, exemplificando:

Existem diversos tipos de falta e cada um com o seu total, por exemplo,

> "Joãozinho teve 20 faltas por dor no pé e 10 faltas por preguiça"

A minha primeira variável, retornaria os números 20 e 10, agora a segunda deveria fazer a soma destes resultados e mostrar. Porém quando tento fazer isso de forma convencional, que seria criando uma variável e no `value expression` atribuir a outra, o iReport simplesmente fica louco e faz algumas somas sem pé nem cabeça.

Segue o código:

```
<variable name="TOTDIAS_LICENCA" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="LICENCA_PRORROGA" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{TOTDIAS}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="variable1" class="java.lang.String" resetType="Group" resetGroup="LICENCA_PRORROGA" calculation="Sum"/>
<variable name="DIAS_PRORROG" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="LICENCA_PRORROGA">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{TOTDIAS_LICENCA}.compareTo( $F{DIAS_MINIMO})>0 ?$V{TOTDIAS_LICENCA}.subtract($F{DIAS_MINIMO}) : new BigDecimal(0)]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="TOTFINAL" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="AQUISITIVO" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{DIAS_PRORROG}]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Olá boa noite antes de mais nada, caso não saiba o iReport esta em desuso, o pessoal tem usado o Jasper Reports para desenvolvimento, que é baseado no eclipse muito parecido com o iReport. Dito isto variáveis tem tempos de execução quando usados em componentes alem disso como pode ver neste print essa variável simples reseta o seu valor ao termino do grupo Condutor OS que na minha regra tem sentido ocorrer neste momento.

[image: Propriedades Variavel]

Ja nesta outra eu tenho uma soma e o reset apenas no final do report e deve ser incrementada apenas no grupo Condutor OS ou seja é um contador geral de todos os registros diferente da de cima que conta apenas no local do meu subreport

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E como eu havia dito sobre o evaluation time dos TextField, nessa propriedade você vai notar que consegue manipular de acordo com a sua situação usando vários valores, NOW, REPORT, PAGE, COLUMN, BAND, AUTO, MASTER alem dos groups que você cria, talvez no ireport seja um pouco diferente ou não possua algum desses valores, mas sem duvida o seu problema de calculo esta nesses estados do TextField e ou nos reset ou incremente da variável.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A unica solução para seu problema e você realizar varias combinações usando esses valores ate chegar no que precisa e ou ate que consiga entender como funciona, é um pouco complexo e o exercício sem duvida vai ajudar de mais na sua evolução com a geração dos relatórios.